# HTTP 500 response using retrofit, but Post request through Postman gives desired response

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

I am using Retrofit to execute POST request. While testing from postman I am getting correct response. But, when I send same request through my app I get response 500. below is my log :

> 12-09 22:44:14.571 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: ---> HTTP POST http://xyz/WebService/api/User/GetCompany
>   12-09 22:44:14.571 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   12-09 22:44:14.571 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Token: JlkXkiBN3YHNLJtOBFT7aeRs1wgmo590SP+D5zA8eOaM0vl64odu/yZxYUGMAc1MKRs44av6naM=
>   12-09 22:44:14.571 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Content-Type: application/json
>   12-09 22:44:14.571 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Content-Length: 2
>   12-09 22:44:14.571 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: {}
>   12-09 22:44:14.571 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: ---> END HTTP (2-byte body)
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: <--- HTTP 500 http://xyzWebService/api/User/GetCompany (268ms)
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Cache-Control: no-cache
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Pragma: no-cache
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Expires: -1
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=is5jp3wopax03vlu5ltlz1zz; path=/; HttpOnly
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 17:14:06 GMT
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: Content-Length: 4931
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1449681254592
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1449681254847
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"could not execute query\r\n[ SELECT c.company_name, c.company_code\n          FROM {SECURITY_USER}.company$module a,{SECURITY_USER}.module b,{SECURITY_USER}.erp_company c,\n          {SECURITY_USER}.user$company d,{SECURITY_USER}.jll$user e,{SECURITY_USER}.erp_financial_year f\n         WHERE a.module_code = b.module_code\n           AND a.company_code = c.company_code\n           AND a.company_code = d.company_code\n           AND e.user_code = d.user_code\n           AND e.rec_status = 'A'\n           AND d.user_code = :p0\n           AND b.rec_status = 'A'\n           and f.company_code = c.company_code\n          -- AND b.short_code = 'SM'\n         group by c.company_name, c.company_code\n         ORDER BY c.company_name ]\r\n  Name:loginUsercode - Value:\r\n[SQL: SELECT c.company_name, c.company_code\n          FROM {SECURITY_USER}.company$module a,{SECURITY_USER}.module b,{SECURITY_USER}.erp_company c,\n          {SECURITY_USER}.user$company d,{SECURITY_USER}.jll$user e,{SECURITY_USER}.erp_financial_year f\n         WHERE a.module_code = b.module_code\n           AND a.company_code = c.company_code\n           AND a.company_code = d.company_code\n           AND e.user_code = d.user_code\n           AND e.rec_status = 'A'\n           AND d.user_code = :p0\n           AND b.rec_status = 'A'\n           and f.company_code = c.company_code\n          -- AND b.short_code = 'SM'\n         group by c.company_name, c.company_code\n         ORDER BY c.company_name]","ExceptionType":"NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException","StackTrace":"   at WebService.Common.Framework.Common.BaseApiController.ExecuteQuery[TParameters,TResult](TParameters parameters)\r\n   at WebService.Web.Controllers.API.UserController.GetCompany()\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"ORA-00911: invalid character\n","ExceptionType":"System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)\r\n   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)\r\n   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavi
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: or behavior, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)\r\n   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)\r\n   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session)\r\n   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)\r\n   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)\r\n   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)"}}
>   12-09 22:44:14.841 9191-10538/com.employee.panorbit.logisticmanager D/Retrofit: <--- END HTTP (4931-byte body)

I am attaching the screenshot of postman also.
[image]

Here post request doesn't require any body. I am sending only header in request. I tried with empty JSON as well as no body request but getting same error.

Comment: The stacktrace says you have an invalid character in the SQL. Could it be that a var coming from Retrofit is different than in your postman test?

Comment: I contacted my Server team, They had problem in maintaining the session, so no variable was retained and hence database query couldn't be executed. There is no problem from retrofit or android application side.

Comment: show how your api interface and how you requested

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov the issue was from server side, not the client side. My server team has fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @kamal_prd, Please mention what was the issue ? 
your server team faced ?
I am getting same issue

Comment: @SHH this problem was due to database issue, this is what they told me.